# Will Xamarin Studio 5 work with Xcode 6 Beta?

Tags: xamarin-studio, xcode6

I currently have Xcode 5 and Xamarin Studio 5 installed; the latest stable version releases of both. I would like to install Xcode 6 Beta to try out Swift, but I don't know if it'll mess up Xamarin, which I need to keep functioning.

Can Xamarin Studio 5 and Xcode 6 Beta be installed side-by-side on the same machine?

Comment: Can you rely on Time Machine and "just try it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Xcode 6 beta side by side with Xcode 5. You can use `xcode-select` to switch between the different versions of command line tools so that it doesn't break your Xamarin stuff.

Comment: Currently I have XCode 6 beta 5 installed parallell to XCode 5. Running xcode-select -p returns "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer", which should be XCode 5. But when I build and run an app in Xamarin nothing happens. What have I missed?